# How to control the metrics sent by statsd to graphite?

Tags: graphite, statsd

I am using hosted graphite and statsd. I want to reduce the costs, by reducing the metrics been sent.
For example: for each timer, I don't want to send all 14 metrics (upper, std...), but only 3 of them (mean_90, sum, and maybe another one).

How can I configure that in the statsd configuration file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the statsd docs and [its source](https://github.com/etsy/statsd/blob/master/lib/process_metrics.js), I don't think you can configure it to not send all the metrics.

I suggest that you either:

1. Edit the source code to only calculate and send the metrics you want. This is probably easy to do just deleting the lines where they are calculated.
2. Configure Graphite to drop all metrics coming from statsd not matching the three patterns you want.